# How to catch FileNotFoundException for two files?

Tags: java, try-catch, filenotfoundexception, throw, throws

I have two text files and I want to throw an exception if the files are not found. I have a class FileReader that checks if the files exist and in my main I try to catch the exception.

```
    public FileReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
         super();
         File file1 = new File("file1.txt");
         File file2 = new File("file2.txt");

         //Throws the FileNotFoundException if the files aren't found
         if (!file1.exists()) {
             throw new FileNotFoundException("File \"file1.txt\" was not found.");
         } else {
         //do something
         }
         if (!file2.exists()) {
             throw new FileNotFoundException("File \"file2.txt\" was not found.");
         } else {
         //do something
         }
```

In another class, I want to catch the exception if the files are missing.

```
public class FileIO {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
         //do stuff
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This works great if only one file is missing. But if both file1 and file2 are missing, I only catch the exception for the first missing file and then the program ends. My output is:

```
File "file1.txt" is not found.
```

How can I catch the exception for both? I want it to output:

```
File "file1.txt" is not found.
File "file2.txt" is not found.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the error message first before throwing the exception.

```
public FileReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    super();
    File file1 = new File("file1.txt");
    File file2 = new File("file2.txt");

    String message = "";

    if (!file1.exists()) {
        message = "File \"file1.txt\" was not found.";
    }
    if (!file2.exists()) {
        message += "File \"file2.txt\" was not found.";
    }

    //Throws the FileNotFoundException if the files aren't found
    if (!messag.isEmpty()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(message);
    }

    //do something
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.